# How to use forEach function to get an array of results from an api?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use an array to get specific results from an API to display in a row in a spreadsheet using google script. This is a sample of what the API log looks like:

```
[20-06-07 22:38:53:839 BST] [ {   
"symbol" : "AMZN",   
"date" : "2020-03-31",  
"currentRatio" : 1.07870933748165254,   
"quickRatio" : 0.842142238837801593, 
},{...
```

The code written below seems to work fine until the forEach array, where I get this error:

> "TypeError: results.forEach is not a function"

```
function callAPI(symbol) {

  // Call the api  
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Fundamental Analysis Model");   
  var url = 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/ratios/'
  var apikey = '?period=quarter&apikey=x'
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + symbol + apikey);

  // Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);  
  console.log(data)
  return JSON.parse(json)
  }

function displayFinancials(array) {

  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Fundamental Analysis Model"); 

  var symbol = "AMZN"
  var api = callAPI(symbol);
  var results = api[0]
  var output = []

    results.forEach(function(elem) {
    output.push([elem["currentRatio"],elem["quickratio"]]);
     });

  dataSheet.appendRow([output])
}
```

If anyone can help correct the array so it will output the 2 example results that would be amazing. Thanks!

Log Data:

```
[20-06-07 23:46:12:257 BST] Logging output too large. Truncating output. [ { symbol: 'AMZN',
    date: '2020-03-31',
    currentRatio: 1.0787093374816525,
    quickRatio: 0.8421422388378016,
    cashRatio: 0.341245248460062,
    daysOfSalesOutstanding: 86.28187456926258,
    daysOfInventoryOutstanding: 155.51901394129743,
    operatingCycle: 241.80088851056001,
    daysOfPayablesOutstanding: 330.35316447115713,
    cashConversionCycle: -244.07128990189454,
    grossProfitMargin: 0.4134416582728092,
    operatingProfitMargin: 0.052868048560674334,
    pretaxProfitMargin: 0.04483645231405397,
    netProfitMargin: 0.03359751895244659,
    effectiveTaxRate: 0.21992314513745195,
    returnOnAssets: 0.011458248582973991,
    returnOnEquity: 0.03883748008334355,
    returnOnCapitalEmployed: 0.02390356610399429,
    netIncomePerEBT: 0.7493349098433343,
    ebtPerEbit: 1,
    ebitPerRevenue: 0.04483645231405397,
    debtRatio: 0.7049693090698704,
    debtEquityRatio: 2.3894778771908323,
    longTermDebtToCapitalization: 0.26420092662525785,
    totalDebtToCapitalization: null,
    interestCoverage: 8.41542288557214,
    cashFlowToDebtRatio: null,
    companyEquityMultiplier: 3.3894778771908323,
    receivablesTurnover: 4.230320699708455,
    payablesTurnover: 1.1048781705612143,
    inventoryTurnover: 2.346979901362889,
    fixedAssetTurnover: 0.9700818987130202,
    assetTurnover: 0.34104448602862075,
    operatingCashFlowPerShare: 6.152610441767068,
    freeCashFlowPerShare: -7.491967871485944,
    cashPerShare: 98.97991967871486,
    payoutRatio: 0,
    operatingCashFlowSalesRatio: 0.04060859884429836,
    freeCashFlowOperatingCashFlowRatio: -1.2176892950391645,
    cashFlowCoverageRatios: null,
    shortTermCoverageRatios: null,
    capitalExpenditureCoverageRatio: 0.45091979396615156,
    dividendPaidAndCapexCoverageRatio: null,
    dividendPayoutRatio: null,
    priceBookValueRatio: 18.875658781713444,
    priceToBookRatio: 18.875658781713444,
    priceToSalesRatio: 16.32895085617346,
    priceEarningsRatio: 486.0165680473373,
    priceToFreeCashFlowsRatio: -330.22031626909677,
    priceToOperatingCashFlowsRatio: 402.10574412532634,
    priceCashFlowRatio: 402.10574412532634,
    priceEarningsToGrowthRatio: 74.06250027159547,
    priceSalesRatio: 16.32895085617346,
    dividendYield: null,
    enterpriseValueMultiple: 131.35365201582718,
    priceFairValue: 18.875658781713444 },...

[20-06-07 23:46:12:265 BST] TypeError: results.forEach is not a function
    at displayFinancials(Stock Research & Analysis:123:13)
```

Comment: Could you please `console.log(data)` before returning it on `callAPI` function? The error that you are getting means one of two things: 1) `results` is not an string or 2) `results` is `undefined`.

Comment: @AndrésMuñoz - did you mean not an array? By the looks of it, OP extracts the first item of a parsed response, which is definitely an object. Btw, George, from that the answer why "not a function" should be obvious

Comment: @AndrésMuñoz I have edited into the post to show 'console.log(data)', and still get the same error.

Comment: Thank you, console log data should print in the console the content of data, could you let me check it please?

Comment: Sure, I've copied the log data into the post.

Comment: Thank you I've added an Answer, `for..in` or `Object.keys()` will allow you to iterate over that object.

Comment: Btw, George - if you found Andres's answer useful, please, consider accepting it so others will know that the solution is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `api` indeed is an array, but `api[0]` is an object, `forEach` method cannot iterate objects. [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) or [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) methods will do the trick.

```js
const results = [{ 
        symbol: 'AMZN',
        date: '2020-03-31',
        currentRatio: 1.0787093374816525,
        quickRatio: 0.8421422388378016,
        cashRatio: 0.341245248460062,
    },{ 
        symbol: 'AMZN',
        date: '2020-03-31',
        currentRatio: 2,
        quickRatio: 2,
        cashRatio: 0.341245248460062,
    },{ 
        symbol: 'AMZN',
        date: '2020-03-31',
        currentRatio: 3,
        quickRatio: 3,
        cashRatio: 0.341245248460062,
    }
];

const output = results.map( result => [ result.currentRatio, result.quickRatio ])

console.log(output); // Should print [ [ 1.0787093374816525, 0.8421422388378016 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 3, 3 ] ]
```

Or if you only want the first result it's really simple:

```js
const results = { symbol: 'AMZN',
    date: '2020-03-31',
    currentRatio: 1.0787093374816525,
    quickRatio: 0.8421422388378016,
    cashRatio: 0.341245248460062,
    daysOfSalesOutstanding: 86.28187456926258,
    daysOfInventoryOutstanding: 155.51901394129743,
    operatingCycle: 241.80088851056001,
};

const output = [results.currentRatio, results.quickRatio];

console.log(output); // will print [1.0787093374816525, 0.341245248460062]
```

Comment: Could you please provide what is the ouput that your'e expecting?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I have attemped to rewrite it using your suggestions, however I'm new to javascript and don't know much about it, ,my adjustment is below however it still does not work, are you able to correct it? Thanks.

...
  for(var i in results) output.push(["currentRatio"], ["quickRatio"]);

Comment: The output I am seeking is e.g. the "currentRatio" and "quickRatio" results from the API, then I would appendrow them together on the last row of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Ok so you want `output` to be this array: `[ 1.0787093374816525, 0.8421422388378016]`, am I right?

Comment: I'm glad to help. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplementary answer: `forEach` method does not **exist** on `Object.prototype`, but only on the `Array.prototype` hence the error message "not a function". If you wanted to, you could define your own (although, it is not [advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)).

Instead, you could define a subclass of `Object` with a `forEach` method, if you are more comfortable with it (another best practice would be not to use `class`):

```
class MyObject extends Object { 
  constructor(value) { 
    super(value); 
  }

  forEach(callback, thisArg) {
    const boundCbk = callback.bind(thisArg || this);

    Object.values(this).forEach((value,idx) => {
      boundCbk(value,idx,this);
    });
  }
}

const test = new MyObject();

test.one = 1;
test.two = 2;

test.forEach(value => console.log(value));
```